# karma + jasmine, ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, frontend, karma-runner

My test case is:

```
describe('Test', function(){

    beforeEach(function(){

        browser().navigateTo('/index.html')
    })

    it('test 1', function(){

        console.log('doc',document)
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    })

})
```

My karma config file is:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Oct 09 2013 17:04:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath:'',


        // frameworks to use
        frameworks:['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files:[
            'test/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude:[

        ],


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        reporters:['progress'],


        // web server port
        port:9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors:true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel:config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch:true,

        urlRoot:'/__karma/',
        proxies:{
            '/':'http://localhost:3000/'
        },


        // Start these browsers, currently available:
        // - Chrome
        // - ChromeCanary
        // - Firefox
        // - Opera
        // - Safari (only Mac)
        // - PhantomJS
        // - IE (only Windows)
        browsers:['Chrome'],


        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout:60000,


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun:false


    });
};
```

The specific error it throws is:

```
Chrome 29.0.1547 (Linux) Test test 1 FAILED
    ReferenceError: browser is not defined
        at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/test/test_index.html.js?1381332358000:7:9)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved adding `'ng-scenario'` to `frameworks` in karma-config.js
Now it's like this
`frameworks:['ng-scenario','jasmine'],`

Comment: Note the order is important - `ng-scenario` must come before `jasmine`